# scripting a write command to another user

Tags: bash, shell

I'm testing a script to write a predefined message to another user.  I'm starting by trying to write to myself (two logins on the same machine).  The script hangs without delivering a message until I manually terminate with ctrl+c on the sending login, at which point the receiving login only shows that I sent EOF.  The script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
write myName
message
!kill $$
```

Even when I uncomment the kill command, its like the write command doesn't see the following message.  When i termante the sender with ctrl+c, I see the following....

```
[....]$ ./writeScript.sh
write: myName is logged in more than once; writing to pts/112    (hangs here)
^C./writeScript.sh: line 3: message: command not found
Terminated
[...]$
```

and the receiver sees...

```
Message from myName@myPlace on pts/143 at 09:53 ...
EOF
```

How do I make this message send successfully?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give input to write.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
write myName << EOM
message
EOM
```

or:

```
echo message | write myName
```

Comment: The second suggestion works, though the first does not.  How can I modify the piping command to send multiple individual lines?  I tried  "echo m1 | echo m2 | write myName"  and only the second message sends (probably because echo is trying to pipe to echo which is just silly).

Comment: The heredoc (first example) ought to work, and is the best way to send multi line text.  However, you can also do `echo "text\nover\nmultiple\nlines" | write myName`  (Just enclose multiple lines in quotes.)

Comment: To use multiple echos, do: `{ echo m1; echo m2; echo m3; } | write myName`

Comment: Note that in the previous comment, I am not suggesting embedding the literal string `\n` in the string passed to echo.  Rather, I am notating literal newlines in the comment with `\n`, so that if you were to enter the example in an interactive session, you would type `echo "text<hit return>over....`